# Allow ' and . through to URL on .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule to rename my URLS on my website that allowed letters and spaces through.  I was wondering how I could change my regex's to let single quotes and periods through in the URL as well.  This is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?role=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ ./index.php?role=$1
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w\s]+)&([\s\w]+)$ ./result.php?role=$1&champ1=$2&champ2=$3
```

Comment: You escape them, just like your line 8: `\.` and `\'`

Comment: @Martijn so would the bottom line look like: `RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w\s\.\']+)&([\s\w\'\.]+)$ ./result.php?role=$1&champ1=$2&champ2=$3` ?

Comment: @user1895377: That should work. If not provide a sample URI you want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You escape them, just like your line 8: `\.` and `\'`

Also, you can remove line 9 if you add a questionmark:

```
# These two:
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?role=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ ./index.php?role=$1
# Can be replaced by:
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ./index.php?role=$1

# And if I understand it properly, the last two lines don't happen both:
# You can replace the bottom 3 lines with this:
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ./index.php?role=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w\s]+)&([\s\w]+)$ ./result.php?role=$1&champ1=$2&champ2=$3
```